# SwiftUI: Unable to resize image on a Picker menu on macOS 13

Tags: macos, image, swiftui, picker

My images are not resized in a SwiftUI Picker on macOS 13.0.

```
Picker("", selection: $selectedItemId) {
  HStack {
    Image("icon-descriptor-country").resizable().frame(width: 16.0, height: 16.0)
    Text("Country...")
  }
}
.pickerStyle(.menu)
```

The images are not resized:

[image]

I also tested a label, instead of the HStack.
Same thing.

Any idea is welcome... or it's purely a macos SwiftUI issue.

**EDIT: after new tests, it seems to work with a systemImage BUT NOT with any assets image (png or svg)**

Comment: could there be something else wrong? I tried the code you provided and it worked fine for me

Comment: @yawnobleix On macOS ?

Comment: Mac os (deigned for ipad) if that makes a difference

Comment: works fine with me too - on macOS

Comment: I used straight systemImage and works fine.
how do you add the background color?

Comment: My app is a real multiplaform app. No Catalyst. No Designed for iPad.

Comment: you're right it doesn't work with images. A simple fix would be to resize your asset images to the correct display size.

Comment: I agree. But all my images are SVG... to not have image size problems/versioning issues in theory. ;)